# Press space to continue

Tags: bash, control-flow

How do I stop a bash script until a user has pressed <kbd>Space</kbd>?

I would like to have the question in my script

> Press space to continue or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to exit

and then the script should stop and wait until Space is pressed.

Comment: All this and more is addressed in this SO Q&A BTW: [What is the linux equivalent to DOS pause?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92802/what-is-the-linux-equivalent-to-dos-pause)

Comment: See also: [Pause Shell script until Press Enter in while loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35075364/pause-shell-script-until-press-enter-in-while-loop)

Comment: related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/293940/bash-how-can-i-make-press-any-key-to-continue

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You can use `read`:

```
read -n1 -s -r -p $'Press space to continue...\n' key

if [ "$key" = ' ' ]; then
    # Space pressed, do something
    # echo [$key] is empty when SPACE is pressed # uncomment to trace
else
    # Anything else pressed, do whatever else.
    # echo [$key] not empty
fi
```

Replace `' '` for space at above with `''` for Enter key, `$'\t'` for Tab key.

Comment: You should add -s to not to print the pressed character out on the terminal. And add a linebreak at the end, or the output will continue directly in the same line like the question. Best would be: `read -n1 -rsp $'Press any key to continue or Ctrl+C to exit...\n'`

Comment: This script doesn't work. Just tested it on Red Hat linux... The `else` block always runs, even when the spacebar is pressed.

Comment: @robert It's because you don't use `bash`. It works if you use `read _` instead, if you have some other shell than `bash`.

Comment: Should the `''` contain a space inside?

Comment: This is`''` for an empty string. No space inside. I guess, it also fits, if you enter ENTER or TAB

Comment: what I really dont understand is why spacebar sets `key` to empty string instead of a string with a space.

Comment: @StevenLu, because IFS whitespace characters are stripped from the answer, so if the answer is SPC, TAB or LF which are in the default value of $IFS, `$key` will be empty. It would have been better to do `IFS= read -rn1` here and test again `' '`. See also [Understanding "IFS= read -r line"](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/209123)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas OK, thanks. So, this means that this answer's code (absent fiddling with `IFS` as you describe) would ALSO respond the same if a tab or enter key are pressed...

Comment: @StevenLu yes as already mentioned by rubo77

Comment: I just saw that too. Ha!

Comment: This reads from STDIN, which will cause issues given `pipeline | script.sh` See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/452347/143394) for a solution.

Answer (score 59):

The method discussed in this SO Q&A is likely the best candidate for an alternative to the `pause` behavior that you're accustom to on Windows when doing BAT files.

```
$ read -rsp $'Press any key to continue...\n' -n1 key
```

#### Example

Here I am running the above and then simply pressing any key, in this case the <kbd>D</kbd> key.

```
$ read -rsp $'Press any key to continue...\n' -n1 key
Press any key to continue...
$
```

#### References

- [What is the linux equivalent to DOS pause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92802/what-is-the-linux-equivalent-to-dos-pause)

Comment: I mean why the `$` before the string in here: `-rsp $'Press` ?

Comment: @rubo77 - ah. That's how you can do a literal string with special characters. It's of the form: $' ... '

Comment: @rubo77 - that's different. That's a dollar sign w/ double quotes, I used a dollar w/ single quotes. Please delete that comment, it's wrong.

Comment: Ah, I understand. In case you put escaped sequences inside the prompt-string. see http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting#ansi_c_like_strings

Comment: @rubo77 - yes that notation allows for escape sequences to be included w/o any extra `echo -e "..."` lines. It's much more compact in those situations.

Answer (score 11):

You could create a `pause` function for it to use everywhere in your script like:

```
#!/bin/bash
pause(){
 while read -r -t 0.001; do :; done # dump the buffer
 read -n1 -rsp $'Press any key to continue or Ctrl+C to exit...\n'
}
echo "try to press any key before the pause, it won't work..."
sleep 5
pause
echo "done"
```

Comment: if you are new to shell scripting - you need to put the function at the top of your script before using it

Comment: Perfect solution for my purposes! Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

```
hold=' '
printf "Press 'SPACE' to continue or 'CTRL+C' to exit : "
tty_state=$(stty -g)
stty -icanon
until [ -z "${hold#$in}" ] ; do
    in=$(dd bs=1 count=1 </dev/tty 2>/dev/null)
done
stty "$tty_state"
```

This now prints a prompt without a trailing newline, handles `CTRL+C` reliably, invokes `stty` only as often as necessary, and restores the controlling tty to exactly the state in which `stty` found it. Look into `man stty` for information on how to explicitly control echoes, control characters and all.

You might also do this:

```
printf "Press any key to continue or 'CTRL+C' to exit : "
(tty_state=$(stty -g)
stty -icanon
LC_ALL=C dd bs=1 count=1 >/dev/null 2>&1
stty "$tty_state"
) </dev/tty
```

You could do it with `ENTER`, no `[` tests `]` and no `stty` like:

```
sed -n q </dev/tty
```

Comment: Your two last solutions seem to work fine with `/bin/sh` (e.g. on FreeBSD) too, not only with bash.

Comment: is your answer on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24046880/3926735) equivalent, or even better?

Answer (score 7):

Here's a way that works in both `bash` and `zsh`, and ensures I/O to the terminal:

```
# Prompt for a keypress to continue. Customise prompt with $*
function pause {
  >/dev/tty printf '%s' "${*:-Press any key to continue... }"
  [[ $ZSH_VERSION ]] && read -krs  # Use -u0 to read from STDIN
  [[ $BASH_VERSION ]] && </dev/tty read -rsn1
  printf '\n'
}
export_function pause
```

Put it in your `.{ba,z}shrc` for Great Justice!

Answer (score 6):

Here's a simple solution from [Press SPACE to continue (not ENTER)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/614936/press-space-to-continue-not-enter)

```bsh
read -r -s -d ' '
```

This will wait until you press the space bar. Yes, only the space bar, it wouldn't break if you pressed enter.

Comment: That one has the merit to work both in zsh and bash

Answer (score 4):

Settings `IFS` to empty string suppresses read's default behavior of trimming white space.

```
try_this() {
  echo -n "Press SPACE to continue or Ctrl+C to exit ... "
  while true; do
    # Set IFS to empty string so that read doesn't trim
    # See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001#Trimming
    IFS= read -n1 -r key
    [[ $key == ' ' ]] && break
  done
  echo
  echo "Continuing ..."
}
try_this
```

UPDATE 2018-05-23: We can simplify this by using the REPLY variable, which is not subject to word-splitting:

```
try_this() {
  echo -n "Press SPACE to continue or Ctrl+C to exit ... "
  while true; do
    read -n1 -r
    [[ $REPLY == ' ' ]] && break
  done
  echo
  echo "Continuing ..."
}
try_this
```

Answer (score 2):

lazy one liner:

```
echo "Press any key to continue or Ctrl+C to cancel"
read && do_something.sh
```

the disadvantage is that you lose control when the user press ctrl+c. The script will always exit with code 130 in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Many wonderful answers using `read -rn1` and that will work beautifully UNTIL you press an arrow key, or a function key, or any other key which lacks an ASCII representation and is translated by the terminal into an escape sequence of multiple characters to read. When that happens, you will have garbage characters waiting in the input buffer which will appear in the next `read`.

Don't forget to clear the buffer before and after...

```bsh
    while read -r -t 0.001; do :; done # dump the buffer
    read -r -n1 -p "Press any key to continue..." # wait
    read -r -t 0.001 # dump the rest of any escape sequence
```

The -t is a timeout specification. The 0.001 is a 1/1000 of one second. Not long enough to notice the pause if no data is available, but the timeout is long enough to extract information from a waiting buffer.

The while loop clears the input buffer before waiting for a keystroke. This while loop prevents the user from being able to hit 5 keys to bypass the next 5 "Press any key to continue" notices. Instead, the user must wait until the notice appears before pressing a key will actually continue.

The last read clears any other keys currently waiting to be read. These keys would be the remainder of an escape sequence made by the one keypress.

Translating the escape sequences of varying lengths into a description of the actual keypress is certainly possible, but there is a standard, and you can test for the actual sequence.

```bsh
    while read -r -t 0.001; do :; done # dump the buffer
    read -r -n1 -p "Press any key to continue..." # wait
    read -r -t 0.001 zRest # read the entire escape sequence
    RESULT+="$zRest" # create the actual keypress
```

This appends the remaining buffer onto the result of the `read` whose keypress may create a multi-character escape sequence. It will work well until someone presses multiple keys at the same time. But if that happens, it is probably better to reject the mess as an unknown keypress anyway.

Comment: I think you are missing to put the first part into RESULT

Comment: And I would add -s to disable printing of the output