# Print currently pressed keys to stdout and read them line by line

Tags: keyboard, read

I want to know which keys are pressed on my keyboard and print the information to stdout.

A tool that can do this is `showkey`. However, if I want to pass the data of `showkey` to `read`:

```
while read line; do
  echo "$line" | otherprog
done <`showkey -a`
```

OR

```
showkey -a | while read line; do
  echo "$line" | otherprog
done
```

Then `showkey` waits until a sum of 140 characters is typed in and then sends the buffered information to `read`.

`showkey -a` prints the pressed keys line by line, without any buffering.

1. Why does it buffer?
2. How do I avoid this buffering, so that I can read `showkey`'s output truly line by line?
3. Is there an alternative to `showkey`?
4. Is there a file I can read the pressed keys directly from?
5. What is the correct way to pass data to `read`?

---

#### Solution:

I've used [lornix's solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/144408/72471) and included it into my simple keyboard keyboard :D!

```
stdbuf -o0 showkey -a | while read line; do
  perl -e 'print sprintf "%030s\n",shift' "$line" | aplay &> /dev/null &
done
```

---

Lasership version:

```
#!/bin/bash
MP3=(); for i in mp3/*.mp3; do MP3+=("$i"); done
NMP3=${#MP3[@]}
stdbuf -o0 showkey -a 2>/dev/null | while read line; do
    [ -z "$line" ] || ! [[ $line =~ ^[0-9] ]] && continue
    NUM="$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $2}')"
    mplayer "${MP3[$(($NUM % $NMP3))]}" &>/dev/null &
done
```

In the same folder, [download some laser mp3 files](http://soundjax.com/laser-1.html) into a folder called `mp3`.

Comment: if youve used iornix's solution, you should probably switch accepted answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try setting `showkey` output to non-buffering with the [`stdbuf`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stdbuf) command:

```
stdbuf -o0 showkey -a | cat -
```

Will show the output as keys are pressed, rather than buffering a line.

`stdbuf` can adjust the buffering of `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr`, setting them to **none**, **line buffered**, or **block buffered**, with a choosable block size.  Very handy.

Comment: Thank you that worked very well :). If I only had two `accept answer` buttons :(.

Answer (score 4):

It buffers because your terminal is set to a line-oriented line-discipline. You need `stty raw`. Try this:

```
state=$(stty -g) 
key=$( (stty raw ; dd bs=1 count=1; stty $state) </dev/tty 2>/dev/null)
```

But that will only work for single-byte keypresses. It might be a good idea to do`LC_ALL=C` first if there's a chance that the input could contain multi-byte kepresses. A more sophisticated example might look more like this:

```
{   exit=$(printf '\003')
    tty_state=$(stty -g)
    stty raw istrip
    while key=$(
        dd bs=1 count=1
    ) ; do : "${key:=
}";     printf " %03o %03d %#x\n\r" \
            "'$key" "'$key" "'$key"
        [ -z "${key#"$exit"}" ] && {
            stty "$tty_state"
            break
        }
    done 2>/dev/null
} </dev/tty
```

Comment: @polym - I found [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/134443/52934) from a month or two ago that deals with a lot of the same stuff. There are others there, too, that are pretty good.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work when pressing CTRL and similar :(.

Comment: @polym - Hmm, I think that is strange, as it does for me. Can you try the update? Quit with CTRL+C.