# Press SPACE to continue (not ENTER)

Tags: bash, shell-script, read, wait

I know this question has been already asked & answered, but the solution I found listens for space **and enter**:

```bsh
while [ "$key" != '' ]; do
        read -n1 -s -r key
done
```

Is there a way (in **bash**) to make a script that will wait **only** for the space bar?

Comment: what should it do when the users hits some other key? (not if, when.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I suggest to use only `read -d ' ' key`.

> `-d delim`:   continue until the first character of DELIM is read, rather
> than newline

---

See: `help read`

Comment: Wow! Thank you. This is what I was looking for. @OskarSkog If you mean if it'll show what you're typing, then yes, this will show the keys you're pressing in the terminal, but you can disable it by adding `-s` flag, like `read -s -d ' '` (you don't need the key variable here, if you only want it to wait for the space key)

Comment: @adazem009 No, I was asking about buffering not echoing. The man page for bash's read doesn't clearly mention it but it obviously works without waiting for a line feed.

Comment: @adazem009 On the negative side of things, `read` is painfully inefficient: it makes a system call for each character it reads (which is kind of why it can do this trick of reading a space without needing Enter). For more reasons to avoid using `read` unless you have no other option, please see Stéphane's excellent answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/88378