# Add a "Press Enter to reboot" at the end of the script

Tags: bash

I am trying to add a "*Press Enter to reboot*" at the end of the script, this is for combining two `cd`s together and rebooting on user command, I have completed first

```
#!/bin/bash
#go into folder
echo "Run ./install to start installation"
cd /usb/folder
./install_one.sh
echo "installing part 2
./install_two.sh
echo "Finished with installation"
echo "Press Enter to Reboot"
Reb=${Reboot}
echo ${Reb}
```

update:
added read -n1 -r -p "Press enter to continue..." enter
if [ "$enter" = '' ]; then
reboot
fi

at the end of it
would this work or does it need something

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Press space to continue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134437/press-space-to-continue); just replace `' '` there with `''`

Comment: thank you for that, I will try it soon and see if it works